# UIButton @selector never actioned when I click on the button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, selector

i have a UIbutton which calls a method in the same class , i'm using @selector and passed the method name,i set a break point and notices that the method isn't reached at all, i wrote this code and i think it works properly, but it never reaches the method body:

```
- (IBAction)setEndTime:(id)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showEndTimePicker" sender:sender];
UIViewController *TimePickerVC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"setEndTime"];
packtimePicker=(UIDatePicker*)[TimePickerVC.view  viewWithTag:2];
NSLog(@"PickerTag%i",packtimePicker.tag);
self.finishedTime=packtimePicker.date;
//     NSLog(@"Date returned is ---> %@",finishedTime);
UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[TimePickerVC.view viewWithTag:3];
NSLog(@"Button Tag%i",btn.tag);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(setSelectedValueToAttr:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

method:

```
-(void)setSelectedValueToAttr:(UIButton *) sender{
finishedTime=packtimePicker.date;
NSLog(@"Time returned----> %@",finishedTime);}
 }
```

Comment: Did you checked if btn instance is defined as UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if you get the correct button back? what is your log displaying? It should be `ButtonTag3` - is it like that?

Is the method `setSelectedValueToAttr:` in the class refered by `self`?

If all that is correct your button probably just doesnt get any touches because of your view structure.

Comment: yes it returned 3 and the method setSelectedValueToAttr: is i the the class referred to by self

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the title of the button to confirm you are indeed getting back the button you want.

```
[btn setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I wouldn't trust the tag logging to confirm that you are getting back the exact button you think you are getting. This should narrow down the issue.

Also, confirm that userInteractionEnabled is set to YES for the button and it's parent views.

Comment: i have only one button in my view controller

Comment: i tried this but it didn't change the title of the button!! what happens

Comment: there's your problem :) you're getting back a different object, not the button.

Comment: 2012-05-02 19:21:25.382 MeetingRoomProject[11907:17603] PickerTag2
2012-05-02 19:21:25.383 MeetingRoomProject[11907:17603] Button Tag3
2012-05-02 19:21:25.595 MeetingRoomProject[11907:17603] PickerTag2
2012-05-02 19:21:25.596 MeetingRoomProject[11907:17603] Button Tag3
2012-05-02 19:21:26.121 MeetingRoomProject[11907:17603] PickerTag2
2012-05-02 19:21:26.123 MeetingRoomProject[11907:17603] Button Tag3

Comment: Chances are, something else has a tag of 3. Try changing the tag to something like 9, and then see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have wrong tag numbers assigned. Check out the example below where I check the kind of class before casting it to UIButton.

```
 UIView *someView = [self.view viewWithTag:5];

    if([someView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *) someView; 

        NSLog(@"uibutton");
    }
    else 
    {
        // some other control 
    }
```